# Train schedule from Montreal to Toronto

Tags: trains, canada, public-transport

I have to take the train from Montreal to Toronto one way. Just want to make sure it's in the schedule.

Comment: What research have you done up to now? Your question doesn’t make clear exactly what you want help with.

Answer (score 3):

The schedule is published on the train website [here](https://www.viarail.ca/sites/all/files/media/pdfs/schedules/november2015/14-15_Toronto-Kingston-Montreal.pdf) with the first train at 06:40 and the last at 18:00:

[image]